# Bootstrap row height option

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

First post - be gentle :)

I've run into an issue with row height in Bootstrap (I think). I'm brand new to Bootstrap and I'm trying to do some basic edits to my Wordpress site and really want to further my knowledge. Previously I had 4 items equally distributed across the page and it looked great. Well, I've added a fifth item and it's been dropped to the next row below the first four but isn't low enough on the page and blocks the content of one of the original four items.

**How can I adjust the height of the offending row(s) to drop the bottom item low enough to accommodate the upper row?**

Link to the actual page: [HERE](http://www.h2htpe.com)
Please see image and code below.

[Offending item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MhLYv.jpg)

HTML from the entire page:

```
<?php
/*
template name:Home Page
*/
get_header();
?>
<!-- banner starts -->
<div class="banner">
  <div data-ride="carousel" class="carousel slide" id="carousel-example-captions">
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li class="" data-slide-to="0" data-target="#carousel-example-captions"></li>
        <li data-slide-to="1" data-target="#carousel-example-captions" class="active"></li>
        <li data-slide-to="2" data-target="#carousel-example-captions"></li>
      </ol>

  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
  <?php $slides = get_field('slides','4');
  if(is_array($slides) and count($slides)>0){
  $num=0;
                  foreach($slides as $slides_val) {?>
    <div class="item <?php if($num==0) echo "active"; ?>">
  <img src="<?php echo $slides_val['slide_image']['url']; ?>" alt="900x500" data-src="holder.js/900x500/auto/#777:#777" data-holder-rendered="true">
  <div class="carousel-caption">
    <div class="banner-heading">
    <span><?php echo $slides_val['slide_content_heading']; ?></span>
    </div>
    <?php echo $slides_val['slide_content']; ?>
  <!--  <a href="<?php// echo get_site_url();?>/contact">Contact Us</a>-->
  </div>
</div>
<?php $num++; } }?>

  </div>

  <!-- Controls -->
      <a data-slide="prev" role="button" href="#carousel-example-captions" class="left carousel-control">
        <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a data-slide="next" role="button" href="#carousel-example-captions" class="right carousel-control">
        <span aria-hidden="true" class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- banner ends --> 
<!-- content starts -->
<div class="content">
<div class="process-section">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="process-heading">Our Process</div>
      <div class="process-fillers-section">
        <ul>
        <?php
                                    global $post,$paged;

                                    $args = array( 
                                        'post_type'=>'process',
                                        'orderby'=>  'post_date',                                       
                                        'order' => 'DESC'
                                            );
                                $wp_query= new WP_Query($args);
                         $no_of_posts=$wp_query->found_posts;

                                while ($wp_query->have_posts()):$wp_query->the_post();


                             $src= wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID),'full');

                                ?>

          <li class="col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
            <img src="<?php echo $src[0];?>" alt="" />
            <div class="process-inner">
            <div class="filler-title"><?php the_title(); ?></div>
            <?php the_content(); ?>
           <!-- <a href="<?php //the_permalink();?>">Read More</a>-->
            </div>
          </li>


          <?php
   endwhile;
?>

        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <?php include('vip.php');?>
  <div class="service-section">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
      <div class="process-heading">Our Services</div>
        <div class="process-fillers-section">
          <ul>
           <?php
                                    global $post,$paged;

                                    $args = array( 
                                        'post_type'=>'services', 
                                        'order' => 'ASC'
                                            );
                                $wp_query= new WP_Query($args);
                         $no_of_posts=$wp_query->found_posts;

                                while ($wp_query->have_posts()):$wp_query->the_post();


                             $src= wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID),'full');

                                ?>
            <li class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3">
              <div class="process-fillers-image-section">

                <img src="<?php echo $src[0];?>" alt="" />

                <div class="process-category"><?php the_title(); ?> </div>
              </div>
              <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?> </p>

              <a href="<?php the_permalink();?>">Read More</a>
            </li>
<?php


                                endwhile;
                                ?>



          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="instagram-section">
  <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
   <div class="process-heading">
<div><img src="<?php bloginfo('template_url');?>/images/instagram-icon.png" alt="" /></div>
   @H2Htpe</div>
 <?php  echo do_shortcode('[instagram]'); ?>

  </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- content ends --> 
<?php get_footer('footer'); ?>
```

Comment: Offending little bastard -  LOL!!!!

Comment: Offending language is simple way to get downvotes! Dont do that. Please edit your question asap.

Comment: A working example would help. I can only guess that you need, at least, to give some height to your row, something like `.service-section .row { height: 400px; }` in your css file. 400px is only a random value.

Comment: Can you post some more of your html (maximum possible)? When fixing layout, at least that is required. Without knowing html one can not fix layout errors.

Comment: Pankaj, here the html from the entire page.  Thanks in advance.